# CodePrimitiveExpression and booleans

Tags: c#, codedom

Here's [an MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.codedom.codeprimitiveexpression%28v=vs.90%29) which describes the CodePrimitiveExpression class which is to be used in order to generate a literal.

It provides a small list of types which can be used with CodePrimitiveExpression .

Boolean is not contained in the list. Yet i have no issue using a literal boolean for the constructor. In fact, I can pass a reference type to the constructor.

```
CodePrimitiveExpression exp1 = new CodePrimitiveExpression(true);
CodePrimitiveExpression exp2 = new CodePrimitiveExpression(new Person());
```

Am I to assume that using anything outside the list documented on MSDN will result in inconsistent behavior during code generation?

Has anyone used boolean based CodePrimitiveExpressions without issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CodePrimitiveExpression` supported values depend on the provider. The C# and VB.NET provides supports boolean value (and unsigned values while there are not in the documentation). If you have a doubt you should look at the source code:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs#50763a00a82de7a5#references

Comment: Thanks for the source code link, new to me and obviously a powerful tool I will be using in the future. After looking at the source, I am at a loss as to why passing a reference type is not causing a runtime exception.